# iPhone 5s crashing infrequently, despite restoring

Tags: crash, iphone

I just got my new iPhone 5s last week. Sometimes it crashes. Even App Store, Music and Voice Memo crash, but it does not happen frequently. Then there are about two times the phone freeze for a moment while I was browsing through my photo and when I was downloading app. Here is my diagnostic and usage screenshot:

[image]
[image]

I have restored my phone to factory setting yesterday but the problem still persists, so is my problem serious or is it normal? Since the Apple Store is quite far from my house, is it worth my time travelling there?

Comment: I can't answer this authoritatively, but I've had problems with crashes as well.  I suspect there are bugs in iOS7 on the 5s and not hardware problems.  If that's the case, going to the apple store won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would absolutely recommend a genius bar appointment if it's convenient and they can be sure your phone is reporting these crashes to Apple Engineering. That being said, you have a totally normal volume of logs and glitches for a new OS release that hasn't had time to have all these little bugs patched.

Of the messages you listed, these are harmless and diagnostic whether you have an app crash or not:

- awdd-YYYY-mm-dd-hhmmss-whatever-else
- log-aggregated-YYYY-mm-dd-hhmmss-whatever-else
- LowMemory-YYYY-mm-dd-hhmmss-whatever-else

Your phone is set up report each crash anonymously (they strip the identifier of the device from the reports intentionally) and the genius bar will ensure you are reporting these so that Engineering can make sure the most common crashes get sorted out.

The other benefit of the genius bar is they can run hardware diagnostics. You can also get these to run by seeking phone or web support in many areas:

- http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/contact/

Click the link that says you can get connected with an expert online.

Now, if you can't get to the genius bar, I can also say that they won't likely be able to dig into any of the crash logs other than perhaps the LowBattery log and LowMemory log and they will just look at them with you. You can look at them and figure out mostly what is going by reading the english descriptions and ignoring most of the hex (0x2f8107c6) and UUID (3A197A6D-1D9B-4F1D-BE12-356F8D3F3C2B).

LowBattery logs are how Apple (and the astute user) can tell if the battery needs replacing or if the programs are just using too much power in the background. LowMemory logs are just diagnostic - kind of like keeping your weight so that you can look back and tell when you were gaining, when you were holding steady and when you were losing.

These logs make the most sense when you track them over time and not so much that you have one now to 13 at this point.

Comment: thanks! i'll probably find some time to go to the genius bar though.

Comment: I always learn something on a visit there and in the mean time, you can go to Settings App -> General -> Diagnostics & Usage and tap to have a check mark next to **Automatically Send**

Answer (score 0):

If you restored to Factory settings and then restored a backup then you have proven that he problem is probably somewhere in your backup. Try restoring to Factory settings and setting it up as a new phone. If it still crashes, then take it to the Genius Bar.

I'd suggest adding back applications slowly and restoring any iCloud, Dropbox, etc... settings for your apps and if it starts crashing again, then maybe you can figure out what app caused it to start misbehaving again.

Comment: yeah i did set it up as a new phone. nvm, i'll find some time to go to the genius bar. thanks!

Comment: @Sara, apparently you are not alone. http://www.imore.com/iphone-5s-reportedly-twice-crash-prone

Comment: I'm on my second new 5S in 3 weeks - the first one kept crashing, this new one seems to have the same problem. I restored the phone as new (not from a back-up)... so frustrating!!!! I'm going back the the genius bar in the morning.... RRRRRRR :-(