# iPhone iOS7 hangs and requires restart when Switching between apps

Tags: ios, performance, restart, iphone

Occasionally, the iPhone hangs and requires a restart when trying to switch between apps by double-clicking the home button. Mostly happens when in landscape mode, but yesterday that phone hanged while its in portrait.

Not sure what is causing this but does anyone else experience this ?

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Have a look at this thread and consider editing in some logs once you find what is crashing when you see the freezes... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104988/iphone-5s-crashing-infrequently-despite-restoring

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. It happens to me on occasion and I've heard that it's not an isolated occurrence.

Comment: @Mark not sure why either of you would have down-voted my question.

Comment: @Render votes are anonymous for reasons - one is to stop these sort of questioning. I have not voted the question down and I have no idea if bmike did, the point is that someone thinks your question needs improving